# Cannot find module '.tmp/Rx.min.js'

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, gulp

I have *Ubuntu os 16.04 version and 
Node : v6.6.0
Npm  : 3.10.3*

I am trying to configure **project with gulp getting one common issue**
[Error Message: Cannot find module '.tmp/Rx.min.js'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQKRW.png)

I am runing below command to build gulp environment:

```
npm run build.dev
```

You can see error message in this image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQKRW.png

Answer (score 6):

You may have already discovered the answer but since this is still the top search result, the issue is described here: [Cannot find module ./tmp/Rx.min.js](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/issues/1501)

You don't mention it specifically in your question but I'm going to assume you're using the [angular-seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed) project.

The likely cause is that the original `npm install` failed for some reason and therefore the build.bundle.rxjs gulp task was not run. You can run it manually or try to sort out why `npm install` failed during the original run.

```
gulp build.bundle.rxjs
```

Answer (score 3):

I found one another solution that need to run below command:

```
 npm run-script postinstall
```

source : [Cannot find module ./tmp/Rx.min.js](http://guruquest.net/question/node-js-cannot-find-module-tmp-rx-min-js/)